# GameCenter - code for submitting score to game center does not work - Xcode - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, game-center

I have this code for submitting my score to game center however whenever i submit the score inside game center it says my score is 0. I am not sure how this happened? I also have imported the GameKit framework.I have looked at several tutorials all of which were from a previous version of Xcode but i am not sure if that makes a difference.

```
-(IBAction)submitScore{
if (highscore>0) {

GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"MyLeaderBoardID"] autorelease];

scoreReporter.value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:highscore] longLongValue];
NSLog(@"posted");
NSLog(@"%i",highscore);

[scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"failed!!!");
        NSLog(@"%i",highscore);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Succeded");

    }
}];}
```

I also have this code for signing in:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"authintication success");
}
else{
NSLog(@"authintication failed");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Center Disabled"message:@"For Game Center make sure you have an account and you have a proper device connection."delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}];

```
self.currentLeaderBoard = @"MyLeaderBoardID";
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the leader board you set on iTunes Connect has "MyLeaderBoardID" as its **Leaderboard ID** ? I don't see anything wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make an int64_t and set it as scorevalue...

Answer (score 0):

Well I am fairly new in iOS programing and trying to learn score reporting to game center. But when I check your code I am guessing two possibilities:

1) "scoreReporter.value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:highscore] longLongValue];" might want a string value rather than a number value

2) The ID of your leaderboard might NOT be "MyLeaderBoardID"

Other parts seem to be fine in my view.

Comment: How is this different from the answers provided in may 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way...

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"ID"];
```